# delphi rtti access array in record

Tags: delphi, rtti

I want to enumerate field information (name, type, …) of a record.  RTTI delivers field name but type is null(nil)! How can I get this information?

Record:

```
 foo = record
  bar : array[0..5] of char;
 end;
```

Enumeration:

```
  for var f : TRttiField  in TRTTIContext.Create.GetType(TypeInfo(foo)).GetFields do
  begin
    OutputDebugString(PWideChar(f.Name + ' :: ' + f.FieldType.ToString())); ///fieldtype is nil??!
  end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The RTTI system only works with predefined types. Defining field types "on-the-fly" does not generate RTTI information.  So, declare the array type like this instead:

```
type
  TChar5Arr = array[0..5] of Char;

  foo = record
    bar : TChar5Arr;
  end;
```

And you will get some more info:

```
name: bar
type: TChar5Arr
value: (array)    //is not retrieved using GetValue
```

Answer (score 0):

Per Delphi's documentation:

[Querying for Type Information](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Querying_for_Type_Information)

> In Delphi, type information is emitted **only for types** and not for global unit routines, constants, or variables. This means that the obtained TRttiContext can be used only to query for information about the **declared types**.

Comment: I feel that this snippet lacks context. What does "this" refer to? Did you intend to emphasise "declared"? What's the conclusion? You may want to add a few words to this answer.